# How to control playback volume of Bluetooth headset when using its mic?

Tags: windows, wireless-headset

I can't control volume if some app uses mic. Volume just stays being the same whatever value I set on volume slider. Can I somehow get control of the playback sound when using headset with its mic? I'm using Windows 11. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the Absolute Volume feature, and restore volume control to older Bluetooth audio devices:

Open a CMD prompt as Administrator and paste the following code and press enter:

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Bluetooth\Audio\AVRCP\CT /v DisableAbsoluteVolume /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

If you decide you want the feature back, you can re-enable Absolute Volume by pasting this code into a CMD prompt as Administrator:

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Bluetooth\Audio\AVRCP\CT /v DisableAbsoluteVolume /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

A reboot is required for the change to take effect.

Now enjoy your music at the volume level you prefer!

Taken from [here](https://www.askwoody.com/forums/topic/windows-11-bluetooth-audio-no-volume-control-fixed/). However not very elegant solution.